# How to enable page scoring in nutch 2.x based on inlinks and outlinks?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Nutch 1.x had this ability, however i cannot find it in nutch 2.x. Is there any option in nutch that can enable it or i have to do it on my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nutch 2.x has OPIC as default scoring mechanism, If you have not deactivated it in your configuration file, you could see scores in s:s column if you are using hbase. I recommend using hive with hbase for SQL syntax. Mitch also has another scoring plugin "scoring.link", it works like pageRank algorithm would work. You can set it up in your configuration file.